# Cast object back to original type

Tags: vb.net, list, casting, derived-class

I have objects in a `List(of BodyComponent)` the `BodyComponent` is a baseclass, The items beeing added into the list are objects from a derived class.

```
Public Class Body_Cylinder

' Get the base properties
Inherits BodyComponent

' Set new properties that are only required for cylinders
Public Property Segments() As Integer
Public Property LW_Orientation() As Double End Class
```

Now I would like to convert the object back to it's original class `Body_Cylinder` So the user can enter some class specific values for the object.

But I don't know how to do this operation, I looked for some related posts but these are all written in `c#` of which I don't have any knowledge.

I think the answer might be here but .. can't read it [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301082/cast-boxed-object-back-to-original-type)

Comment: If you know the type, you can use [CType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x2877xb.aspx). CType(theList(0), Body_Cylinder).Segments = 0

Comment: The link refers to boxing which is slightly different than you want.  Since the base has an itemtype property use that to know which it is, then `CType` to convert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`Enumerable.OfType`-](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) LINQ method:

```
Dim cylinders = bodyComponentList.OfType(Of Body_Cylinder)()
For Each cylinder In cylinders
    '  set the properties here '
Next
```

The list could contain other types which inherit from `BodyComponent`.

So [`OfType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) does three things:

1. **checks** whether the object is of type `Body_Cylinder` and
2. **filters** all out which are not of that type and
3. **casts** it to it. So you can safely use the properties in the loop.

If you already know the object, why don't you simply cast it? Either with `CType` or `DirectCast`.

```
Dim cylinder As Body_Cylinder = DirectCast(bodyComponentList(0), Body_Cylinder)
```

If you need to pre-check the type you can either use the [`TypeOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ec5kw18.aspx)-

```
If TypeOf bodyComponentList(0) Is Body_Cylinder Then
    Dim cylinder As Body_Cylinder = DirectCast(bodyComponentList(0), Body_Cylinder)
End If
```

or the [`TryCast` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyy863x8.aspx):

```
Dim cylinder As Body_Cylinder = TryCast(bodyComponentList(0), Body_Cylinder)
If cylinder IsNot Nothing Then
    ' safe to use properties of Body_Cylinder '
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but not exactly what I am looking for, I know exactly what object I need to convert from the baseclass to the deriverd class. I want to do this so I can open load this object its property values into a form with textboxes.

Comment: @Mech_Engineer: if you already know it, why don't you cast it? Either with `CType` or `DirectCast`.